# Get all contact names and numbers as a string list on Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I found this nice looking layout for a contact list: https://github.com/thehung111/ContactListView

However the contacts are hardcoded. So **I need to fetch phones contacts and fill the contact list.**

Here's what I have tried:

```
public class ExampleDataSource  {

public static List<ContactItemInterface> getSampleContactList(){
     List<ContactItemInterface>  list = new  ArrayList<ContactItemInterface> ();


     Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
     Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

     int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
     int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

     people.moveToFirst();
     do {
         String name   = people.getString(indexName);
         String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
         list.add(new ExampleContactItem(name , number ) );

     } while (people.moveToNext());

     /* Example inputs for contact list

     list.add(new ExampleContactItem("Lizbeth" , "Lizbeth Crockett" ) );
     list.add(new ExampleContactItem("Lizbeth" , "Lizbeth Crockett" ) );
     list.add(new ExampleContactItem("Zachery" , "Zachery Loranger" ) );
     list.add(new ExampleContactItem("Vada" , "Vada Winegar" ) );
     list.add(new ExampleContactItem("Essie" , "Essie Pass" ) );

    */   
     return list;
}
```

}

I got error on getContentResolver() and tried to extend class to an Application etc. No luck this far.

**So the main question is how to get a list that contain names and phone numbers as a string list on Android.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared below permission in your manifest? If not then please declare it.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it will show all contacts Name and their phone number each in new line:

```
String names="";

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,null,null,
                                          null);

                                    while (people.moveToNext()) {


                                        int i=people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                                        int i2=people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID);
                                        String name=people.getString(i);
                                        String id1=people.getString(i2);
                                        names+=name+":";
                                        Uri uri2 = ContactsContract.
                                                CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                                                String[] projectio = new String[] {
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.
                                                Phone.NUMBER }; 
                                                String selectio= ContactsContract.
                                                CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +
                                                "=?";
                                                String[] selectionArg = new String[]
                                                {id1 };
                                                Cursor peopl=getContentResolver().query(uri2,null,selectio,selectionArg,null);
                                                while(peopl.moveToNext())   
                                                {
                                                    int i3=peopl.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                                                    String phonenum=peopl.getString(i3);
                                                    names+=phonenum+"\n";


                                                }

                                             }
Log.d("names":names);
```